# mrtk2.6.2 Error in VS2019 CS0246, and it cannot recognise MRTK

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, mrtk, cs0246

This Error is only in VS2019.
This Error never happens before. Idk if it was becasue i misclicked something in VS.
In Unity there is no Error message and everything works fine, even playmode.

But when I open a random script that is using methods in MixedReality.Toolkit, there will be warnings that "***"(e.g, Interactable) **is not a Unity Component**, and error message that I am not using the toolkit or no reference(CS0246 error).

I not very good at coding so I don't know what can I do to fix it....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.